# How do i Swap INPUT Eelement with Animation? Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

Actually i want to show sorting Example visually, i tried so many ways but still not get the right path where to move and to be get done ?
what still i have tried is

1. `getBoundingClientRect()`
2. **swap input values(i do not want to swap values but swap whole element
           visually)**

but none of the above is good for me, can any one lead me to the nicer direction so i can achieved my task ?

```
function BubbleSort(){
    var VisualSort=[];
    var inputElements = document.forms["BubbleSortForm"].getElementsByClassName("formControl");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputElements.length ; i++){
        VisualSort[i] = parseInt( inputElements[i].value );
    }

    // var inputValues = parseInt( inputElements[i].value );
    for( var i = 0 ; i  < inputElements.length-1  ; i++ ){
        for( var j = 0; j <  inputElements.length-1 ; j++ ){
            if( parseInt( inputElements[j].value ) > parseInt(inputElements[j+1].value )  ){
                 /*var swapa = inputElements[j].value;
                 inputElements[j].value = inputElements[j+1].value;
                 inputElements[j+1].value = swapa;*/

                 var input_id      = inputElements[j].id;
                 var input_id_swap = inputElements[j+1].id;

                 var Bounds_j   = inputElements[j].getBoundingClientRect();
                 var Bounds_j_1 = inputElements[j+1].getBoundingClientRect();

                 var elem = document.getElementById(input_id);
                 var elem_swap = document.getElementById(input_id_swap);

                 var pos_left_1 = inputElements[j+1].getBoundingClientRect().left;
                 var pos_right_1 = inputElements[j+1].getBoundingClientRect().right;

                 var pos_left = inputElements[j].getBoundingClientRect().left;
                 var pos_right = inputElements[j].getBoundingClientRect().right;

                 var jplus1 = j+1;

                 inputElements[jplus1].style.left = pos_left + 'px';
                 inputElements[jplus1].style.right = pos_right + 'px';

                 inputElements[j].style.left = pos_left_1 + 'px';
                 inputElements[j].style.right = pos_right_1 + 'px';
             }
         }
     }
     document.getElementById("btnSort").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("btnGenerateInput").style.display = "block";
     return VisualSort;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: then why tagged jquery-animate?

Comment: bubblesort function is working onClick ....and jquery-animate is tagged by mistake

Comment: Please can Some one help me to achive above Task ??